# Fixed Length Formatting for Combination of Fields in Python logging modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, logging, flask

I am using the Python logging module in my application. Here is my current format.

```
LOGGER_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)-5s [%(threadName)-10s] %(name)s.%(module)s.%(funcName)s : %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format=LOGGER_FORMAT)
```

And a sample output:

```
2018-03-14 11:35:27,257 INFO  [Thread-2  ] my_app.util.get_login_info : Log line 1
2018-03-14 11:35:27,257 INFO  [Thread-2  ] my_app.cache.call : Log line 2
2018-03-14 11:35:27,257 INFO  [Thread-2  ] my_app.web.parse_response : Log line 3
```

What I am looking for is that I get the message displayed from the fixed position instead of varying start points.

I am able to configure the fixed length for each individual attribute, but I wanted to configure a fixed length for the entire `name.module.funcName` part, so that my output is like below:

```
2018-03-14 11:35:27,257 INFO  [Thread-2  ] my_app.util.get_login_info : Log line 1
2018-03-14 11:35:27,257 INFO  [Thread-2  ] my_app.cache.call          : Log line 2
2018-03-14 11:35:27,257 INFO  [Thread-2  ] my_app.web.parse_response  : Log line 3
```

Is it possible, and how can I configure this?

Comment: that would be a nice feature indeed

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would be to use a `logging.Filter` such as:

```
class MyFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        record.expandedFuncName = '%s.%s.%s' % (record.name, record.module, record.funcName)
        return True
```

and then use a format string something like

```
%(asctime)s %(levelname)-5s [%(threadName)-10s] %(expandedFuncName)-20.20s : %(message)s
```

You'd need to ensure that an instance of this filter was applied to every handler which uses a formatter with `expandedFuncName` in the format string. You can't do this with `basicConfig`, so I'd recommend using the `dictConfig` logging configuration API instead.

Note that the logger name will generally include the module name if you use the convention `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` as recommended in the logging documentation, though this won't apply exactly in the case of the `__main__` module.